# How can i check mail log error .. php mail in godaddy hosting

Tags: phpmailer

PHP mail function is returning true  but not sending the mails and I want to check the mailer logs for any bounce back from SMTP..
Godaddy says:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1456/what-if-ive-reached-my-servers-smtp-limit
for vps(VIRTUAL PRIVATE SERVER)
I am having my shared server with dedicated ip.. and I can't see any such folder for mailer logs.

No comments yet.. please provide a sol where i can confirm where exactly it is blocking...
i can't move further without logs